# Understanding the MLP neural network - Python without a library

Tags: python, neural-network

I have a hard time learning about neural networks. Let's start with my understanding of that. In the phase of obtaining the result, it is simple, weights * inputs + bias and a function (sigmoid) is applied.
My problem is in the backpropagation phase, as much as your calculations or your wrong choices about the number of neurons.

Let's get to my understanding of backpropagation:
expected - production,
make your derivative, transpose the previous layer, calculate the gradient with error * derived from the output and correct the bias and weights, my results are sometimes random.

```
    # INPUT -> HIDDEN

    matriz_inputs = array_matrix(inputs)
    hidden = self.weights_ih@matriz_inputs + self.bias_ih
    hidden = 1/(1+np.exp(-hidden))

    # HIDDEN -> OUTPUT

    output = self.weights_ho@hidden + self.bias_ho
    output = 1/(1+np.exp(-output))
    
    # # BACKPROPAGATION

    # OUTPUT -> HIDDEN
    expected = array_matrix(target)
    output_error = expected - output
    derivate_output = output*(1-output)

    hidden_T = hidden.T

    gradient = output_error*derivate_output
    gradient = gradient*self.learning_rate

    self.bias_ho = self.bias_ho+gradient

    delta_weights_ho = gradient@hidden_T
    self.weights_ho = self.weights_ho+delta_weights_ho


    # HIDDEN -> INPUT

    weights_ho_T = self.weights_ho.T

    hidden_error = weights_ho_T@output_error
    derivate_hidden = hidden*(1-hidden)

    matriz_inputs_T = matriz_inputs.T

    gradient_H = hidden_error*derivate_hidden
    gradient_H = gradient_H*self.learning_rate

    self.bias_ih = self.bias_ih+gradient_H

    delta_weights_ih = gradient_H@matriz_inputs_T
    self.weights_ih = self.weights_ih+delta_weights_ih
```

This is the training code.

And here are some exits

[image]

[image]

It was expected [0,0,1,1], the second image shows a correct correction, but the first does not. Xor Problem

```
Neurons are:
input (i) = 2
hidden (h) = 2
output (o) = 1
```

The frequency of the error occurs with the change in the number of neurons in the hidden layer or in the number of layers (I coded only one layer, but I coded several in another code).

My problem is in calculations or neurons, because with 4 (hidden neurons) this error did not occur

EDIT:
I posted images of the code because I understand that they will be easier to visualize, because my problem is not in its execution, but in the understanding of the calculations and data choices, not being necessary to execute it.